# Error: npm ERR! node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` in deploy AWS EB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploy my app in AWS EB, occurs this error:[Print1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyJ3n.png)
[Print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp6MJ.png)

Error:
**npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9
npm ERR! node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 9
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2024-01-30T19_44_24_333Z-debug.log
Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
Setting npm config jobs to 1
npm config jobs set to 1
Running npm with --production flag
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
UTC 2024/01/30 19:44:24 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log**

I not user root of AWS

NODE: 18.19.0

When user root realize deploy not occurs this error
I want to know because happening and what do to fix that ?